# Delete prior XML File until new file generated using Java

Tags: java, xml, file, file-io, java-io

On a regular interval am writing to an xml file at a specified location using [PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) with data coming from database.
I don't want to delete the existing xml file until the generation of xml is fully completed in current run as in case of any issues while generating xml i would be left with no xml file.
Would appreciate any recommendations around handling this scenario wherein the deletion of current file will hold off until generating/writing the file in the current run is fully completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the new XML to a temp file, then move/rename the old file, then move/rename the temp file to the real file name, and finally delete the old file. That way you always have a file in place and don't delete the old file until the new file is in place.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this kind of thing is to rename the original XML file with a different filename.

Simple version:

```
If 'file.xml' exists Then
    If 'file.xml.bak' exists Then 
        remove 'file.xml.bak'
    Fi
    rename 'file.xml' as 'file.xml.bak'
Fi
generate XML to 'file.xml'
```

The flaw in this version is that if the application (or system) fails after renaming, the next time you run that application may see an incomplete or missing `'file.xml'`.  You can address this by having the application try to use the backup file if it detects either scenario.

Alternatively, you can introduce a third file; e.g. get the application to generate `'file.xml.new'` and do the renaming AFTER the write has succeeded.  You still have to cope with a missing `'file.xml'` under some circumstances: it is unavoidable unless you have a transactional file system.   However, the window for failure is smaller, and you should always complete copies of the current and backup files.

Comment: How about generating the file in current run with a different name, then once file in current run is generated..delete the prior file and rename the current file.

Comment: @John C - yea ... though you are assuming that rename won't fail in a way that deletes the file that it is trying to rename.  (That's a fair assumption in most circumstances.)

Comment: +1 for the edits. I won't attempt renaming unless deletion of prior file is sucessful.